# Que veut dire « mettre quelque chose dans la vue de quelqu'un » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, registre-familier

(I recently bought a funny cartoon book with funny one-liners under every picture. But given that I am still learning French and it is difficult to understand jokes in the language one learns, please help me understand to get this joke.)

A child says this to a butler, apparently playing perhaps video game with his master:

> *Une vraie pomme*, ton patron, *ça fait cinq parties que je lui mets dans la vue*.

I understand neither “mettre dans la vue” nor “une vraie pomme” in this context.

Comment: I suggest you ask a question for each language item that is bothering you because as such we don't know what part of the language you don't understand, for example you could ask *what's "une vraie pomme"* when talking about a person, or [*mettre dans la vue*](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=39522). Apart from 1) it all seems pretty straight forward and the help of an online dictionary should help you.  If you need help for a complete sentence you could ask in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette).

Comment: Thanks @Laure, I have italicised the parts I did not understand. I guess the problem especially with using an online dictionary is that even though one might get the exact meaning, humor is something which many times has a deeper meaning.

Comment: @Laure I don't understand what the slang meaning of *pomme* is here. I might understand with the picture I suppose.

Comment: @Gilles: en argot une pomme c'est quelqu'un de naïf, de crédule.  (On dit aussi une poire...)

Comment: @Gilles: I guess I should have scanned the picture. C'est dommage, I gifted the book as a new year/xmas present to someone after I posted my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Pomme” is slang for someone who is stupid, easily fooled. And ”mettre dans la vue” means “to take advantage on someone, to be ahead”.

From what you describe of the picture we have two adults: a man, his boss and the man's child; the two men are playing and the kid's watching them.  But the caption would make more sense to me if the kid was playing with his dad's boss. 
Anyway here's what I understand without more information: “Your boss is a real dunce, I've been ahead for five games/I've won five games.”

Comment: You are absolutely right. The child is playing with the boss. Merci for your kind answer